# Can the same user get two or more Enthusiast or Fanatic badges?

Tags: support, badges

As far users can get two or more of Nice Question or Nice answear badges, does Enthusiast or Fanatic badges works the same way? Which badges are avaiable to get more than one time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only receive each of these badges once (per SE site).

You might also find the [list of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) post on MSO helpful.

Comment: Which ones can a user get more than 1 time?

Comment: @Diogo there's lots you can and lots that you can't have a look at the badge list I've linked to - to states which badges are singular and which aren't.